# How can I get the mean value of an array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to calculate the mean value of the last 10 elements.
First I am reading out the data from a file:

```
np.genfromtxt(filename,skip_header=6, names=True)
```

First I tried to use numpy.mean function but I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```

So I decided of writing a function:

```
def get_mean_values( marray, nr ):
    """
    """
    # Creating an empty array
    tmp = np.delete( marray[-1:], 0, 0 )

    for key in marray.dtype.fields:
        tmp[key] = np.append( tmp[key], np.mean( marray[key][nr:] ) )


    print tmp
    return tmp
```

But the tmp array is always empty. How can I calculate and store the mean value of the last 10 elements.

This is how my data looks

```
array([ (99.9, 9.0),
       (100.0, 9.0) ....], 
      dtype=[('Time', '<f8'), ('HorWind', '<f8')])
```

Comment: You need to define what the 'mean' means over these tuples like (99.9, 9.0).   Also you should try the mean method here, once you know:  https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean   Looks like your problem is that you're trying to compute the mean of a bunch of tuples not numbers.

Comment: I am trying to get the mean of the Time(99.0, 100) and the HorWind(9.0, 9.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mean function works just fine as long as you are specific enough :)

```
import numpy

x = numpy.array([(99.9, 9.0),
       (100.0, 9.0)], 
      dtype=[('Time', '<f8'), ('HorWind', '<f8')])

print 'Time', x['Time'].mean()
print 'HorWind', x['HorWind'].mean()
```

Output:

```
Time 99.95
HorWind 9.0
```

Comment: This is a solution, but I would like to store the data in the same structure as the original array.

Comment: The `dtype` comes from your question so it should be the structure you currently have. Otherwise I apparently don't understand your question correctly

Comment: I would like to store the mean values: `tmp['Time'] = x['Time'].mean()`. I tried the following `tmp[key] = np.append( tmp[key], np.mean( marray[key][nr:] ) )` but the `tmp` variable is always empty and I don't know why.

Comment: you cannot append to a struct array; the underlying datastructure of a struct array is a C-struct, not a dynamic python type. If you want additional entries in your struct, you will have to create a completely new array.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if that helps, but a general function to compute the mean of the last ten elements of an array would be:

```
array = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]

def lastten(index):
    return sum(index[-10:len(index)])/10

print lastten(array)   --> 15
```

Comment: Or just `np.mean(index[-10:])`

Comment: `np.mean(index[-10:])` is not working, I am getting the error mentioned in the question.

Comment: You just need to access the field, as in Wolph's answer. `np.mean(x['Time'][-10:])`. My coment was more of an improvement to what 386er did.

Comment: Well maybe because the entries of your array are tuples and not single values ?